# Set location programmatically when Tweeting using TWTweetComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, tweets

I have a location stored (an address and lat/lon coords) along with some additional information (name, description, image, url, etc.) that I'd like to tweet using the Twitter framework. How can I pass the location information to the tweet sheet? I don't want to have to rely on the user tapping the "set location" button on the twitter controller, and besides tapping this sets the location to the users current location, not the pre-stored location that I want to use in the tweet...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Impossible. There is no API to set the location for a tweet, the system will always use the user's location.

Comment: Thank you. Post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted if you like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible. There is no API to set the location for a tweet, the system will always use the user's location.